# what type is the object,an Operation or a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

See the code:

```
 c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
 d = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
 e = tf.matmul(c, d)
```

I want to know ,what is the type of e ,an Operation or a Tensor?

Comment: Why not look at the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul#returns) and see for yourself?

Comment: Let me assist on this. You find the documentation to ```tf.constant``` here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant . Please keep the title of your question a title and not just the plain question which should be presented within the text. The title should just frame the issue itself.

Comment: In docs.
For example c = tf.matmul(a, b) creates an Operation of type "MatMul" that takes tensors a and b as input, and produces c as output.
It seems likely , c is an Operation.but also in docs (/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul),it seem that it 's  a Tensor

Comment: Why don't you just try `type(e)`? This is much faster than waiting for someone to answer...

Answer (score 0):

As we know, TensorFlow builds a computational graph which contains `Tensors` and `ops`.

First, you defined two constants namely `c` and `d`. They are tensors.

```
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]])
d = tf.constant([[1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]])
```

Now, we define a operation on the TF graph named `tf.matmul` which takes in two tensors present in the graph. The `tf.matmul` operation ( or `op` ) multiplies both the tensors and returns the product as a tensor.

According to the docs, `tf.matmul` returns,

> A `Tensor` of the same type as `a` and `b` where each inner-most matrix is the product of the corresponding matrices in `a` and `b`.

```
e = tf.matmul(c, d)
```

**Hence, `e` is a `tf.Tensor` which is the result of the operation `tf.matmul` with two tensors as inputs namely `c` and `d`.**

Comment: In docs, https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/Operation.
It says,Objects of type Operation are created by calling a Python op constructor (such as tf.matmul),So i was confused.